# Magento shows an order multiple times

Tags: sales

Very new to Magento and I recently had a customer place an order. However, under my sales, it shows up multiple times for the exact order.

So this order had `3 order numbers`, but it's all the same thing. When I check the order information, it states it was purchased from the following:

```
Main Website
Main Website Store
Default Store View
```

Could that be a reason, why? If so how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how many stores do you have?